# Google sheets APIv4 grouping of columns

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I'm getting a

```
"endIndex": end_number 
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

error with this code:

```
def group_columns(self,key,sheet_name,column_start,column_stop):  
        sheetId=self.get_id(key,sheet_name)
        start_number=col2num(column_start)-1
        end_number=col2num(column_stop)
        print(end_number)
        data={'requests':
          [
            {
              "updateSheetProperties": {
                    "columnGroups": [
                        {
                            "range": {
                                        { "sheetId": sheetId,
                                          "dimension": "COLUMNS",
                                          "startIndex": start_number,
                                          "endIndex": end_number
                                        }
                             },
                             "depth": 1,
                             "collapsed": "True"
                        }

                    ]
               } 

             }
          ]
        }
        results=self.service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=key, body=data).execute()
```

all I'm trying to do is group a few columns and I followed the reference here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#DimensionGroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create the group in the spreadsheet. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

### 1. Add group

[Your request body can be used when the spreadsheet is created using `sheets.spreadsheets.create`.](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#sheet) If you want to add the group to the existing spreadsheet, you can use the following request body.

```
data = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "addDimensionGroup": {
                "range": {
                    "dimension": "COLUMNS",
                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                    "startIndex": start_number,
                    "endIndex": end_number
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

### 2. Update group

If you want to update the existing group, you can use the following request body. In this case, please use the same range with the existing group you want to update.

```
data = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "updateDimensionGroup": {
                "dimensionGroup": {
                    "range": {
                        "dimension": "COLUMNS",
                        "sheetId": sheetId,
                        "startIndex": start_number,
                        "endIndex": end_number
                    },
                    "depth": 1,
                    "collapsed": true
                },
                "fields": "*"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

From [the document](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#dimensiongroup),

> This field (`collapsed`) is true if this group is collapsed. A collapsed group remains collapsed if an overlapping group at a shallower depth is expanded.

### Reference :

- [AddDimensionGroupRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#adddimensiongrouprequest)
- [DimensionGroup](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#dimensiongroup)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: @jason I'm sorry. About your request body, I had misunderstood. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? The request body of your question can be used when new spreadsheet is created using ``sheets.spreadsheets.create`` and ``{"sheets": [{"columnGroups": [ ,,, ]}]}``.